# Having trouble lerping a game object back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have this hand icon that I want to move back and forth. So far I have it set up inside a coroutine like this

```
elapsedTime +=Time.deltaTime;
float percentageComplete=elapsedTime/desiredDuration; 
transform.position=Vector3.Lerp(startPosition,endPosition,percentageComplete);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);
transform.position=Vector3.Lerp(endPosition,startPosition,percentageComplete);
```

But it's giving me this weird twitching motion after it completes one round of going from start to finish and back again. It start snapping between startPosition and endPosition.

How do I resolve this. I also want this game object to destroy itself after 3 seconds. Is it possible to use one coroutine inside another?

Comment: Can you show your complete coroutine? currently there is no smooth motion at all but only a one time movement before and after waiting for 0.9 seconds .... how exactly is this called ... and note that you are just lerping back with the same percentage as the lerp before ... you want to start over from `0`

Comment: It's called once in the update function

Comment: again: please share a complete code example and explain exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: You might want to rather use [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) then which does this already without any routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you resetting the elapsedTime?

You don't need a Coroutine to move the object back and forth. You can just check if your percentageComplete variable is equal to 1 and swap the start and end point. Also reset the elapsed time.

Source: https://vionixstudio.com/2021/11/03/how-to-lerp-in-unity/#How_to_check_if_lerp_is_done_in_unity

> Is it possible to use one coroutine inside another?

Yes you can.